# .tmux.conf の escape-time について

Tags: tmux

`.tmux.conf` の設定例などを見ていると、以下のように `escape-time` 設定を 0 にしている例をしばしば見かけます。

```
set-option -s escape-time 0
```

man ページを見ていると、これは「エスケープシーケンスの一部かどうかを判定するために wait する時間」だと書いてありますが、これはどうして 0 にしてしまっていいのでしょうか。

(もしくは、これを 0 にすることによって引き起こされる可能性がある問題としては、どのようなものがありますか？)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manページを見ると「if it is part of a function or meta key sequences.」とありますので「Esc + A」とかそういう操作をしやすくするために 遅延させてるのだと思います。

`0`にすることで遅延がなくなり Esc キーをおした時の操作感が速くなります。
Vim では Esc キーを多用するのでそのように設定している人が多いようです(この情報にはソースはありませんが・・・)。

> Set the time in milliseconds for which tmux waits after an escape is
>   input to determine if it is part of a function or meta key sequences. 
>   The default is 500 milliseconds.

日本語だと

ミリ秒を指定します。Function またはMeta key sequence の一部であるかを決定するために Escape が入力された後に Tmux は 待ちます。デフォルトは 500 ミリ秒です。

という感じでしょうか。

Comment: ああ、なるほど。`ESC+A` で `M-A` と認識させるか、 `ESC`+`A`と認識させるか、そのための delay 時間がこれなのですね。理解しました。

Comment: 正確には、端末によってはM-Aというキーの組み合わせがESC+Aとしてプロセスに送られるってことです。プロセスからはユーザがESCとAを連続して押したのかM-Aを押したのか原理的には区別できないので、ディレイを見て区別するわけです。他にも上矢印キーがESC+[+Aとか色々あります。ウィンドウシステムから直接イベントを取れる場合は矢印キーは矢印キーとわかるのでこういった区別は必要ありません。

Comment: @shirok なるほど、 tmux 自身 が `M-`系の処理を行うので、 ESC を受け取ったときに、自身がそれを受け取るか、管理している仮想端末にそのまま流すか、それを判断するために wait する時間が、ここで設定されているのだと理解しました。